# Need to purposely Fail JMS to invoke Error Handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling, jms

I am trying to purposely make a JMS call fail in a method I've already written to test out my JMS Error Handler. I've tried a few different methods such as passing null values, etc to the queue but none have been successful in invoking my JMS Error Handler. Anyone know of a quick way to get the correct error for testing purposes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By "Error Handler" I assume you mean JMS [ExceptionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ExceptionListener.html). If that is true, it's worth noting that the ExceptionListener is only invoked when an exception for the corresponding Connection cannot be delivered any other way. My recommendation would be to programmatically kill the broker while the test is running. If that isn't feasible for you then you'll need to find some other kind of way to forcibly break the connection during the test.

Comment: The goal of it is to catch any JMSException's and then using the handleError method override correctly handle the error, I just can't figure out how to do a simple call mid-method to make it throw a JMS exception.

Comment: Where is the `handleError` method coming from?  It's not part of either the JMS 1.1 or 2.0 specification.  Based on your question's tags I assume it's coming from Spring, but you don't mention this in either the title or the question itself.  I'm not very familiar with Spring so it's hard to make assumptions here.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, Yes, It is the spring error handler that implements the ErrorHandler interface.